# Solana: Computational budget exceeded

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-transaction-instruction

I am using the Saber deposit instruction on devnet. Yesterday, my code was working perfectly fine.

Today, I reran some of the instructions, and I am getting the error `Computational budget exceeded` all of a sudden. Did something on devnet change? I literally have not changed anything, yet getting this error. Any ideas and pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which cluster you are running on. It is feature driven whether each instruction gets a 200 K CU budget or the entire transaction gets the 200 K budget.

For example, if you are running `solana-test-validator` all features are enabled by default. However; the Tx wide compute budget is not yet enabled on mainnet-beta so if you test locally and then run on mainnet-beta you will see this behavior difference.

To determine what features are enabled or not on a given cluster (ignoring local for the moment):

`solana feature status -ud` (for devnet)

`solana feature status -ut` (for testnet)

`solana feature status -um` (for mainnet-beta)

The feature you are looking for is: `5ekBxc8itEnPv4NzGJtr8BVVQLNMQuLMNQQj7pHoLNZ9`

Good writeup about cluster parity testing [Feature Parity Testing](https://solanacookbook.com/guides/feature-parity-testing.html#facts)

Answer (score 0):

As stated here
[https://forums.solana.com/t/transaction-failed-when-biding-for-a-sol-domain-on-bonfida/4279#:~:text=%E2%80%9CComputational%20budget%20exceeded%E2%80%9D%20means%20that,processing%20power%20before%20it%20completed](https://forums.solana.com/t/transaction-failed-when-biding-for-a-sol-domain-on-bonfida/4279#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CComputational%20budget%20exceeded%E2%80%9D%20means%20that,processing%20power%20before%20it%20completed).
You need to reduce the instructions computational needs. Or reduce the total number of instructions. You can also use Transaction wide compute budgets
https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/runtime

Comment: but so then why did it work for about 2 months until yesterday?